# connecting MS Access through VC++

Tags: visual-c++, odbc

I am new to VC++, I am trying to write a program(after lots of googling) which connects to ms access, but its showing connection error. What am I missing or doing something wrong.

Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid String or Buffer Length.

Here is what I am tring

```
Clearn_dbView::Clearn_dbView()
    : COleDBRecordView(Clearn_dbView::IDD)
{
    setUpODBC();  
}

Clearn_dbView::~Clearn_dbView()
{

    if(hDbConn  != SQL_NULL_HANDLE)
    {
        // Free Connection.
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC,hDbConn);
    }

    if(hOdbcEnv != SQL_NULL_HANDLE)
    {
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hOdbcEnv);
    }


}


void Clearn_dbView::setUpODBC()
{
    SQLRETURN sr;           //Return call for ODBC

    //Allocate Environment.
    sr = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV,SQL_NULL_HANDLE,&hOdbcEnv);
    if( sr != SQL_SUCCESS && sr != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Error in Allocating Environment."));

    // Set the App's ODBC Version
    sr = SQLSetEnvAttr(hOdbcEnv,SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,(SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, SQL_IS_INTEGER);
    if(sr != SQL_SUCCESS && sr != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Error in Setting ODBC Version."));;

    // Allocate Connection
    sr = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hOdbcEnv, &hDbConn);
    //sr = SQLAllocConnect(hOdbcEnv, &hDbConn);
    if(sr != SQL_SUCCESS && sr != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Error in Allocating Connection."));;

    // Set Connect Timeout
    sr = SQLSetConnectAttr(hDbConn, SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (void*)5, 0);
    if(sr != SQL_SUCCESS && sr != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Error in Setting Login Timeout."));

}

void Clearn_dbView::displayODBCError(SQLRETURN sr, char *inMessage)
{
    if(sr != SQL_SUCCESS && sr != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        SQLWCHAR SqlState[6];
        SQLINTEGER NativeError;
        SQLWCHAR ErrMsg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
        int i = 1;
        char message[1000];
        strcpy (message, "");
        if (inMessage) {
            strcpy(message, inMessage);
            strcat(message, " — ");
        }
        sprintf(message, "%sError in SQLConnect(): %d.",message, sr);   
        MessageBoxA(NULL,message,"Error",MB_OK);

        while(SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbConn, i,SqlState, &NativeError,ErrMsg, sizeof(ErrMsg), NULL)
            != SQL_NO_DATA) {
                sprintf(message,"Diag: %d, SQLSTATE: %s NativeError: %d ErrMsg: %s",i++, SqlState, NativeError, ErrMsg);
                MessageBoxA(NULL,message,"Error",MB_OK);
        }
    }
}

void Clearn_dbView::connectwithdb()
{
    SQLRETURN sr;
    SQLCHAR szDSN[] = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN=D:\\Avi\\P\\mydb.mdb.dsn";
    SQLCHAR szUID[] = "";
    SQLCHAR szAuthStr[] = "";
    if(hDbConn == NULL) {
        MessageBox(_T("hDbConn IS NULL"));
        return;
    }
    sr = SQLConnectA(hDbConn, (UCHAR *)szDSN, SQL_NTS,
        (UCHAR *)szUID, SQL_NTS,
        (UCHAR *) szAuthStr, SQL_NTS);
    if(sr != SQL_SUCCESS && sr != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) 
    {
        displayODBCError(sr, "Error in OnViewConnectwithsqlconnect");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(_T("else executed"));
        MessageBox(_T("Connected OK"));
    }

}


void Clearn_dbView::OnBnClickedConnect()
{
    connectwithdb();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the **DSN** being specified in the following line is not valid:

```
SQLCHAR szDSN[] = "D:\\Avi\\P\\mydb.mdb";
```

Based on the string `"D:\\Avi\\P\\mydb.mdb"`, it looks like the database file and path are being specified instead of the **DSN**.

You will need to be sure to create an ODBC DSN using the **ODBC Administrator**.  You will provide a string for the **Data Source Name** field of the configuration.  That string is what you will need to specify in your code for `SQLCHAR szDSN[] = ""`.

[Here](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/3352?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=forum&utm_campaign=support-kb&utm_term=alch&utm_content=odbc) is a link that explains the error in more general details, however; if you follow what is mentioned above, that should resolve the error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I edited my code, as you said but getting error `Invalid string or buffer length`

Comment: What line of code is generating this error?  

Can you share the full error message?

Comment: inside the function `displayODBCError()` , `ErrMsg field`  contains the error, Exact error is this only `Invalid string or buffer length`

Comment: I was hoping to find out which ODBC Call was failing rather than which piece of code was reporting the error.  Can you create an ODBC trace and see which ODBC function is failing?   

If you search for the error message "invalid string or buffer length" in the trace and then work backwards to the last ODBC function that returned SQL_ERROR or SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO.

Comment: I just realized that you edited your code with the changes to the connection details.  I don't think the value you are providing is valid:

DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN=D:\\Avi\\P\\mydb.mdb.dsn

Instead of SQLConnect(), you may want to use SQLDriverConnect().  If you are going to specify "DRIVER=", then you don't need "DSN=".  What type of DSN have you created; System, user, or file?